# Ruby thread pool

Tags: ruby, multithreading

My code runs on every object in my array `stacks_asgs`.

```
begin
    threads = []
    stack_asgs.each do |this_asg|
        t = Thread.new do
            LOGGER.debug 'started new thread for %s' % this_asg
            replace_nodes_in_asg(this_asg)
        end
        t.abort_on_exception = true
        threads << t
    end
    threads.each(&:join)
rescue => e
    LOGGER.error e.message
    exit 1
end
```

How can I edit this code to use a thread pool and only run on three objects at a time?

Comment: Did you attempt to pick a gem that implements a thread pool, check out its README and use it?

Comment: Great, will try https://rubygems.org/gems/threadpool/versions/0.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the thread pool size , clean old thread etc.
Give the code below a try. That's the general way but as suggested above , https://rubygems.org/gems/threadpool/versions/0.1.2 should be used instead of writing something inefficient like the example below.

```
class ThreadsPool
  attr_accessor :threads, :limit
  def initialize(limit = 1, sleep_time = 0.1)
    @limit      = limit
    @threads    = []
    @sleep_time = sleep_time
  end

  def can_add_thread?
    @threads.size < @limit
  end

  def wait_for_spot
    until can_add_thread?
      clean_threads
      sleep @sleep_time
    end
  end

  def add_thread(thread)
    thread.abort_on_exception = true
    @threads << thread
  end

  def clean_threads
    @threads.delete_if { |t| !t.alive? }
  end

  def join_all
    @threads.each(&:join)
  end
end

stack_asgs = [5,6,7]

thread_pool = ThreadsPool.new(2)
stack_asgs.each do |this_asg|
  thread_pool.wait_for_spot
  puts "this_asg -> #{this_asg}"
  thread = Thread.new { sleep this_asg ; puts "end of sleep #{this_asg} | #{DateTime.now}" }
  thread_pool.add_thread(thread)
end
thread_pool.join_all
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, eventually, I followed this guide and it working as expected: https://www.engineyard.com/blog/ruby-thread-pool

Answer (score 1):

```
work_q = Queue.new
stack_asgs.each {|this_asg| work_q.push this_asg}
workers = (0...3).map do
    Thread.new do
        begin
            while this_asg = work_q.pop(true)
                replace_nodes_in_asg(this_asg)
            end
        rescue ThreadError
        end
    end
end
workers.map(&:join)
```

end

Answer (score 0):

> on every object in my array `stacks_asgs` [...] How can I [use] a thread pool and only run on three objects at a time?

```
require 'in_threads'

stacks_asgs.in_threads(3).each do |this_asg|
  replace_nodes_in_asg(this_asg)
end
```

What I was looking for was operating on each line from STDIN, which you can do like this:

```
require 'in_threads'

STDIN.each_line.in_threads(900) do |line|
  download(line.chomp)
end
```

The `in_threads(n)` method is provided by this gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/in_threads
The [source code](https://github.com/toy/in_threads/blob/master/lib/in_threads.rb) is quite short and readable, in case you are weary of third-party libraries for security reasons (like me).

If you want to do more complex things, you might need a different library (or write it yourself: it seems like the `Thread` class in Ruby is rather pleasant). Looking through the features and APIs of at least a half dozen of the more popular gems, this one seemed to be the most mature and straightforward to use in 2021, but I don't know for sure because I didn't actually end up using it: https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby